# Audio tags duration property is returning "infinity"

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, duration

It might be possible duplicate, but i have pretty weird scenario. Use case is to show  duration of the audio for the source set dynamically before even playing the audio. this is what I have tried so far,

```
var tempVid = $document[0].createElement('audio');
tempVid.preload = 'metadata';
tempVid.src =  URL.createObjectURL(mediaObject);
tempVid.load();
tempVid.addEventListener('durationchange',function () {
   var duration = tempVid.duration;
   console.log(duration);
});`
```

also I have tried with "loadedmetadata" event of the media property ,even that didn't help. What I am missing here ?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?