# Audio duration is returned as Infinity

Tags: javascript, html, audio

TLDR;
I'm loading an audio file in my html page via JS and while the file loads perfectly, the audio duration is returned as Infinity. Why?

I'm in a situation similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690433/audio-tags-duration-property-is-returning-infinity), except that I've tried to listen to both the events, `canplaythrough` and `loadedmetadata`. In both these, I'm getting the audio duration as `Infinity`. For clarity, I'm streaming this audio file from another domain through my nodejs server (probably not ethical, but just a PoC). This was working fine for a long time but the issue started appearing recently and I'm not sure why.
A sample of the code is below:

```
       const audio = $audio.load(track, {userClicked: userClicked});
       //service that creates an instance of audio object, sets the source url, calls the 'load' function and returns the instance

       audio.on('canplaythrough', function (e) {
          const secs = e.currentTarget.duration;
          $('.duration', el).html(getReadableTime(secs));
        });


        audio.on('loadeddata', function () {
          // display audio duration in readable form
          $('.duration', el).html(getReadableTime(audio.duration));
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "streaming"? Does your server sets correctly the metadata of the file? Does it respond correctly to Range-Requests?

Comment: I just piped the response from the 3rd party server to my api request. Anyway, fixed the issue. The problem was with content-length and related headers which are nor required for some reason (didn't get into the details). So, except for forwarding content-type header, forwarded all the response headers from 3rd party to my API request and the issue was resolved.